# Can't fetch plugins from repositories with scala's sbt

Tags: scala, ubuntu, ssl, plugins, sbt

I try to compile/build scala project with sbt, there are two plugins mentioned in project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.17")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.4")
```

Error while importing sbt project:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: 
com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.17!sbt-plugin.jar
[error] download failed: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4!sbt-native- 
packager.jar
```

Seems that problem in certificates for repositories, so i manually take each certificate and add it to my keystore with a command (**i use ubuntu**):

```
keytool -import -alias "artifact server2" -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file _.bintray.com
```

But it doesn't help.

Update: i solved my problem by manual adding all certificates (end and intermediate) from repo's hosts to local keystore.

Comment: No idea .. works for me: `[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.3.4/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.3.4!sbt-native-packager.jar (2397ms)` Can you access the URL in your browser ?

Comment: @Stanislav Kapinus Can you please add error output from sbt? How do you understand that this is a certificate issue? Please give as much useful information as you can in the question.

Comment: @ygor yes, I can get artifacts with urls in logging, but sbt shows errors.

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc there are warnings like this:
[warn]  [FAILED     ] com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.17!sbt-plugin.jar: sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.6.17: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.6.17/jars/sbt-plugin.jar: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: @StanislavKapinus try updating your JRE or JDK. Make sure you use latest release of java

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc but i need to use java 8.

Comment: @StanislavKapinus it's still java 8. Check out https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc i have java 1.8.0_191, so it's a latest version of java8.

Comment: I had this problem while running sbt in Intellij. I ran sbt from terminal and it downloaded the package fine. Still problems in the IDE, but at least it helped me move forward.

Answer (score 8):

This issue had me almost ready to throw my macbook out the window.

On my mac, the java cacerts is located here:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

To get ahold of the required certificate for `sbt-native-packager` I used this (which I stole from someone, and now I can't find the attribution):

```sh
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect repo.scala-sbt.org:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/scala-sbt.cert
```

Then to add it to the java trust store, I used Stanislav's solution above:

```sh
sudo keytool -import -alias "scala-sbt server" -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /tmp/scala-sbt.cert
```

*Remember that the default password for the cacerts file is `changeit`*

And then the next time I ran sbt the plugin downloaded and I almost wept tears of joy.