# “PKIX path building failed” and “unable to find valid certification path to requested target” when fetching sbt plugins

Tags: java, scala, ssl, sbt, ssl-certificate

I've installed java (11 - openjdk 11.0.2), scala (2.13.1) and sbt (1.3.4) using homebrew.
Then i tried to add certificate to java's keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias "my-cert" -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts" -file ~/my-cert.cert
```

But when i try to use sbt (via idea or from console) i get these kind of errors:

> :::: ERRORS   Server access Error: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.2/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.2.pom
>
> Server access Error: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.2/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.2.jar
>
> Server access Error: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.2/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.2.pom
>
> Server access Error: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>   url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.2/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.2.jar

I also tried to add certificate for repo.scala-sbt (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746436):

```
keytool -import -alias "scala-sbt" -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts" -file ~/scala-sbt.cert
```

But this also didn't help.
How can i fix this?

---

Tried this:

```
   keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias "my-cert" -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts" -file ~/my-cert.cert
```

And this didn't help to

---

To connect to the internet i use cisco anyconnect. 
All certificate file formats were changed to *.pem as recommended but this didn't help too

Comment: Is there are firewall between your computer and repo1.maven.org that decodes TLS messages?

Comment: @savas i'm not sure, but most likely yes

Comment: Then you may need to add root certificate to keystore and pass keystore to sbt like sbt  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cacerts" compile.

Comment: Still not working :(
Probably, i missed something

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend dividing problem to two parts:

1) Adding required intermediate and root certificates to keystore. Then you can test this step with a simple java application (like SSLPoke) instead of sbt.

https://github.com/MichalHecko/SSLPoke.

2) Ensuring sbt is using the correct keysotre. You can pass your keystore to application using the jvm parameter "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore"

You may use a local artifactory server to mitigate this problem if your corporate is behind a firewall that offloads ssl traffic.